# how to custom the sub-component in Material UI globally

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanna custom the floating Label of TextField.

I know creating a new one works like below, but is there a better way?

```js
import TextFiled from 'material-ui/TextField';

class TextFiledNew extends Component {
    static propTypes = {

    }
    render () {
        return (
            <TextFiled
                floatingLabelFixed={true}
                floatingLabelStyle = {{top: '88px', textTransform: 'uppercase', letterSpacing: '0.1em'}}
            />
        )
    }
}

module.exports = TextFiledNew
```

I tried the changing Theme way, but it doesn't work.

```js
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
    textField: {
        floatingLabel:{
            top: '88px',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            letterSpacing: '0.1'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That works just fine! We use several components with a custom wrapper around them from material-ui. Our `EnhancedMenuItem` lets us add some optional icons and transitions in some circumstances. Definitely experiment with the library and make your own modifications to get it exactly right for your needs.